# How do I trigger a jQuery change function with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

At the moment I have a function that is changed when you select something in a dropdown box. it all works fine. But I want to also call the same .change function in a different function. Is this even possible and if so, how do I do it? Here is the function I wanna call:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
     $('.action').change(function(){
      .....
      .....
```

I hope I provided you with enough information to answer my question, thanks in advance.

Comment: You can create a function, something like `function actionChange() { ..... <logic here> .... }` and assign that function the the change event `$('.action').change(actionChange);` and then you can either call the function directly (`actionChange()`) and it will also be called on the change event

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.on()` and than `.trigger()`

```js
jQuery(function($){  // DOM ready and $ alias in scope.

    $('.action').on('change', function(){
      console.log("Foobarbaz");
    });
    
    $('.action').trigger('change');
   
    $('#myAction_3').trigger('change'); // or a specific one
    
});
```

If you want to trigger only a specific `"change"` you can namespace your event name:

```js
$('.action').on('change.foo', function(){
  console.log("Foobarbaz");
});

$('.action').trigger('change.foo');
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly, you want the same thing to happen at two different places. If that is the case, then you could do something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.action').change(function(){
       onSelectChange(); // call the function on select change
   });

   function onSelectChange()
   {
        // write your code here
   } 

   // your other function which needs to do the same thing as .action change function
   function myOtherFunction()
   {
      onSelectChange(); // call the same function here as well
   }
});
```

Comment: The accepted answer, to me, looks to encourage the interweaving of application logic and jQuery in a most pernicious way. This the sane solution.